# What is X-Titanium-Id?

Tags: android, httpwebrequest

I have been working with android application 
I cam across header X-Titanium-Id what is it and why is it used for ?
can it be removed of the header information ?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're using Titanium Mobile SDK..

It's a custom header added by the SDK HTTP client and the value is set as the Application GUID.As the name suggests, your server can use it to identify the application instance.

[Source](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/blob/master/android/modules/network/src/java/ti/modules/titanium/network/TiHTTPClient.java#L1332)